# How to merge/join two resultset/table in django?

Tags: python, django, join, orm, merge

I'm trying to display a list of employees that are part of the same company. So for example with the given URL localhost/app/company-slug/ I'd like to show a list of rows where there are the details of all three models:

| first_name | last_name | company-slug | employee_status | employee_type |

With this models, how I can retrieve this kind of data?

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)


class EmployeeProfile(models.Model):
    employee = models.OneToOneField(Employee)
    # Base
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=31)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=31, null=True, blank=True)


class EmployeeJob(models.Model):
    employee = models.OneToOneField(Employee)
    # Employment status
    employment_status = models.ForeignKey(EmploymentStatus, null=True, blank=True)
    employment_type = models.ForeignKey(EmploymentType, null=True, blank=True)
```

## Edit 1:

I didn't know was possible join tables within template tags. This is a working solution suggested by @Shang Wang

```
{% for employee in employees %}
    <tr class="table-row clickable" data-href="{% url 'hrm:detail' company.slug employee.pk %}">
        <td><strong>A</strong></td>
        <td>{{ employee.employeeprofile.first_name }} {{ employee.employeeprofile.last_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ employee.employeejob.employment_status }}</td>
        <td>{{ employee.employeejob.employment_type }}</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already had an object for `company` in current page, getting the employees is really easy:

```
employees = Employee.objects.filter(company=company)
for employee in employees:
    print employee.employeeprofile.first_name
    print employee.employeeprofile.last_name
    print employee.employeejob.employment_status
    print employee.employeejob.employee_type
```

Django doc about [OneToOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/).

Comment: Cool, it works, I didn't know was possible join tables in template tags. Btw, it take almost 5.3 seconds to response. Is normal?

Comment: It depends, if you have a large amount of data, yea it's normal. But you shouldn't make the page response time that long. Either do pagination or, if you have some inefficient code that drag things down, fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm compiling  webkit-gtk-2.4.11 and the workload of the laptop is: Load avg: 5.73, 5.69, 5.70. In think the problem is retrieving data from DB cause the CPU is under load. Usually it take 2 seconds to reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

do you have a views.py which serves these models? you could easily use the django [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) function to serve all three of these models to the dom. this is a rather comprehensive, all encompassing process but I'd be more than happy to assist you